# How to do login to my asp.net app using Facebook (or other ID)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, authentication, openid

How do sites like SO allow you to authenticate yourself via Facebook, OpenID, Google, Blogger, Twitter, etc?

I'm writing an ASP.NET (C#) site, and I'd like to be able to accept logins like this, in addition to offering the regular plain vanilla username/password that any other site has.

Where do I start?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to try [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/)

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353973/dotnetopenauth-webforms-getting-started) a similar question on SO with some more links

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you look at http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/

I believe SO may actually use this library - they definitely donated to the project this year (see https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-overflow-gives-back-2010/).