# Using gmail for login through asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, plugins, gmail

I have searched in this site but more of gmail login were related to php.
my problem is connecting gmail login to the website written in C# and asp.net. so the user can enter the website by gmail account. I dont talk about sending email and these areas. its just login in with gmail account! should I write it myself from the beginning? or there is some ready APIs / plugins ??
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the following link which details the login API for using their Google accounts https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/

look the following thread for more details

[OpenID and Google.GData.AccessControl.dll in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759055/openid-and-google-gdata-accesscontrol-dll-in-c-sharp)

[How to do login to my asp.net app using Facebook (or other ID)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594408/how-to-do-login-to-my-asp-net-app-using-facebook-or-other-id)